# Background Image in Existing Stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I'm completely stumped on applying a repeating background image on an existing website.  I usually develop relatively simple websites from scratch and am unfamiliar with manipulating existing more complex code so I may be missing something obvious but here goes.

I'm working with a page and stylesheet with multiple divs and containers where the visible content is restricted to a width of 800px.  I've been trying to apply a repeating bg image to the body in the stylesheet and it doesn't seem to have an affect.

Are there areas in this stylesheet other than the body tag where I should be looking?  Could someone possibly help me with other places where you would commonly look, eg. container css, divs, etc?

Many thanks!

EDIT:  Here's a snippet of code that might help.  I tried applying to the containers but no dice:

```
    html {
    margin: 0;
    /* setting border: 0 hoses ie6 win window inner well border */
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    /* setting border: 0 hoses ie5 win window inner well border */
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana, 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image:url("pix/cork.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

form { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
a { text-decoration: underline; }
a img { border: 0; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: normal; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul, pre, blockquote {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* standard helper classes */

.clr {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

/* .pkg class wraps enclosing block element around inner floated elements */
.pkg:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    height: 0.1px;
    font-size: 0.1em;
    line-height: 0;
}
* html .pkg { display: inline-block; }
/* no ie mac \*/
* html .pkg { height: 1%; }
.pkg { display: block; }
/* */


/* page layout */

body { 
    text-align: center; 
} /* center on ie */

#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10 auto; /* center on everything else */
    width: 420px;
    text-align: left;
}
#container-inner { position: static; width: 400px; }

#banner { position: relative; }
#banner-inner { position: static; }

#pagebody { position: relative; width: 100%; background-color:#fff; margin-top:120px; }
#pagebody-inner { position: static; width: 100%; }

#alpha, #beta, #gamma, #delta {
    display: inline; /* ie win bugfix */
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
}

#delta { float: right; }

#alpha-inner, #beta-inner, #gamma-inner, #delta-inner {
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: Without your code it's kind of hard to tell...

Comment: I'm so at a loss as to where to look that I'd have to post the whole page which would be daunting.  Wondering if anyone would be kind enough to let me email them the files?

Comment: Yeah, SO doesn't really work that way. You need to have a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) in order for us to really help you out here.

Comment: @user3358145 - you are trying to get the background by css in body tag. Everything seems correct. Please check if the image file you are using is in the pix directory. Also check that the image you are using is .jpg and not .png or .gif something.

Comment: All that checks out.  Could it be because this stylesheet is located in a different directory than the pix folder?  (eg. pix is root/pix and this css is in root/videos/evens/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for tags and container to implement the css. Here is the example that could help -

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MyPage</title>
<style>
body{
background-color:#06F;
}
#container {
width:800px;
background-repeat:repeat; /* you can use repeat-x / repeat-y / no-repeat also*/
background:url(path/image.JPG);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div
</body>
</html>
```

You surely need to post your code.

Comment: Thanks so much for trying even though I'm being vague here.  I added a good chunk of the code to see if it helped.  I tried applying the background css to the containers but it didn't seem to work.